# log4net stops working when remove MultipleActiveResultSets="true" from SQL Server connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, log4net

We use log4net in an asp.net application, pointing to a SQL Server.

We removed MultipleActiveResultSets="true" from the connection string and restarted IIS, and the application continued to log.  However, we then re-started SQL Server and log4net stopped working.

We re-added MultipleActiveResultSets="true" to the connection string and restarted IIS, but log4net still did not work.  We then restarted SQL Server with MultipleActiveResultSets="true" in the connection string, and log4net started working again.

Does log4net require MultipleActiveResultSets="true" in the connection string? Is there any workaround where log4net will work without MultipleActiveResultSets="true" in the connection string?

Comment: Seems odd, unless you're using custom code - a) why would log4net query the database anyway? and b) I've used log4net many times without that setting. I'd recommend [enabling log4net debugging](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) and having a look in the output.

Comment: @stuartd, I do have log4net internal debugging turned on, all I get is "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."  I'll add the full error text to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we just needed to restart IIS **after** SQL Server re-started. When we did this log4net started working again, even though the connection string did not contain MultipleActiveResultSets=true.

Comment: Ah yes, [log4net does not by default reconnect to the database after an error occurs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ReconnectOnError.html)